# How to Group Measures and Make Columns Table Source Name

Tags: pivot, union, tableau-api, crosstab, rosters

I'm new to Tableau! I hope this is a simple answers. Thanks in advance!

I'm working with employee data and I need to create a matrix of headcount totals across years and months.

[Final Matrix Output Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfWgs.png)

I'm starting with 6 tables listing all active employees at the beginning of each year from 2015 through 2020. I then have a list of employees and the date that were hired; so all employee additions. I then have the same thing for terminations. All 8 of these tables are in the same Excel file but different tables.

[List of Data Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoTET.png)

How can I take this data and create the matrix I linked above? I've tried creating calculated fields to count the number of active employees for each time period, but I can't then seem to get the matrix to organize itself correctly in a table.

[Current Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85xih.png)

I feel like the easiest solution would be to query this so that I just have a snapshot of all active employees at the beginning of each month and year with month and year columns, but I'm not sure how to convert what I have now, into that sort of structure.

Thanks again.

Comment: This seems like a data restructuring problem instead of querying.  You may have to properly `JOIN` and `UNION` your data into one table before proceeding further. That will, however, depend on present structure of individual tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear you have to extensively restructure your data before proceeding to build a view/crosstab, as is evident from the current status of your data (screenshot shared by you).  You can do it much easily in excel.  Meanwhile, I recommend/suggest you to read the paper by Hadley Wickham, renowned statistician/data scientist at this page https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf

Still, I am trying to give you the steps which you can follow-

**Step-1** Rename all columns of headcount tables by removing years from these.  (Keep year names in sheets instead).  This will give same column names for your all headcount tables.

**Step-2** `UNION` all these headcount tables in data-tab of tableau.  Keep sheet_names in a separate columns which will later-on be used to extract years' values.

**Step-3** `PIVOT` all months columns to rows (In data tab only)

**Step-4** Extract year names from file/sheetname column

**Step-5** This will give a table structure with three useful columns to build your crosstab i.e. 1. `Year` (to be placed in columns); 2. `Months` (to be placed in rows) and 3. `Headcount value` (to be placed on viz/text marks card)

Comment: I think you're right here. This process was exactly what I had in mind, but wasn't sure how to execute. Thanks for the resources!